# #1054 - Unknown column 'Klanten.Klantnummer' in 'on clause'

Tags: sql, clause

I know that I have seen a couple of other questions about this error but I'm new to the sql JOIN so plz could you guy explain what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my query

```
SELECT Klanten.Klantnummer,`Barcode`, `Naam`, `BetaalStatus`, `ScanStatus`, `TijdScan`, `Prijs` 
FROM `Klanten`, `kaart` 
LEFT JOIN (`Intro`) 
ON (Intro.KlantNummer = Klanten.Klantnummer) 
WHERE kaart.KlantNummer = Klanten.Klantnummer
```

This is the Error I get like you have seen in the title

## 1054 - Unknown column 'Klanten.Klantnummer' in 'on clause'

And the db names are correct

Comment: well, does the `Klanten` table have a `Klantnummer` column?

Comment: A side note, but you really shouldn't mix both the implicit and explicit `JOIN` styles.  In fact, you really shouldn't even have a `,` in the `FROM` clause at all.  That style became obsolete **nearly 25 years ago.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  If you did that, you would not have an error:

```
SELECT Klanten.Klantnummer,`Barcode`, `Naam`, `BetaalStatus`, `ScanStatus`, `TijdScan`, `Prijs` 
FROM `Klanten` JOIN
     `kaart`
     ON kaart.KlantNummer = Klanten.Klantnummer LEFT JOIN 
     `Intro`
     ON Intro.KlantNummer = Klanten.Klantnummer ;
```

The problem is that the precedence of `,` and `JOIN` are different.  Hence, the table before the comma is not known to the `ON` clause.